# How can I connect an android client to my XMPP (ejabberd) server, hosted on my local machine (Windows based OS)?

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd

I want to test my ejabberd (xmpp) server, which I've hosted on my laptop, which is working on windows 10 based OS. I want to connect my android client to this server. So I went on to the internet, and found some solutions. But they seem don't work for me. This is what I've tried:

1.) Create a hotspot on a phone. Don't use data/wifi connection, as server is already on the machine.

2.) Connect the laptop to the hotspot.

3.) On cmd (running as admin), type 'ipconfig', after starting xmpp server (Obviously).

4.) Copy IPv4 address (External IP), and access web panel on the mobile browser through it.

So, I hurried toward my phone, and typed

```
http://[IPv4 Address]:[port open on the server for incoming connection/5280]/admin
```

But it(browser) throws 'Can't reach the webpage' error.

When I run

```
http://localhost:5280/admin
```

on my laptop, I could easily access my web portal, but It's unreachable on my android phone. What can I do now?

Comment: Why would you create a hotspot with your phone? Your pc will already be connected to some router. Connect -using wifi- your phone to the same router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved this problem by accessing IPv4 of my laptop through my wifi router, and connecting to the port of my server through it. Initially, my browser (both of my laptop and my phone) weren't able to reach the server's port. But I later figured out it was problem in my .yml configuration file. Server wasn't set to listen all the IPv4 calls, instead it was listening to all IPv6. So I changed this, and it then become accessible to all devices on the same wifi. So it was my bad idea to connect it through the hotspot :P

Comment: Can you please elaborate and go step by step. I am a newbie and couldn't understand a thing.